# How can I invalidate Chrome caching programmatically on client side?

Tags: browser-cache, browser-history, html5-history, history.js

I have the following very specific bug in my web application, caused by a curious interaction between the History API and the way Chrome caches pages.

- User A logs in and uses a page like `/home` on the site. This page is an SPA type page that uses the History API to maintain a history stack as you navigate *within* the page. So as you do stuff, the url may change to `/home/with/new/state` This page also has a message like **"Hello, User 1"** on it.
- User A logs out of the application.
- *On the same computer and browser*, User B logs in and goes to `/home`, `/home/with/new/state`. Again, this is not a true navigation, just modifying the url via the history API.
- User 2 clicks some link to navigate (for real) to another page on the site.
- User 2 clicks the back button
- The browser goes back to `/home/with/new/state`, *but to the cached version that still says **"Hello, User 1"** on it*.

Naturally, this is really confusing for users.

I can fix this by setting a more aggressive cache-control policy, forcing a reload of the `/home` page, but that would increase bandwidth to the site. The vast, vast majority of the time, the existing caching is fine, because the user isn't changing, so I don't really want to do this server side, for all users, always. It also is only an issue in Chrome; somehow the other browsers handle this correctly. I'd prefer a mechanism to bust the cache ONLY when I have this situation of a user change.

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: "I can fix this by setting a more aggressive cache-control policy" -> so right now all your pages have some kind of `Cache-Control: max-age=`. Or is it some other caching?

Comment: At the moment, they use `cache-control: private`

Comment: I think you should restrict in then. and explicy disallow caching.